# I am having problems in displaying images in django project

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to display an uploaded image on my Django website, but it seems I am unable to display it. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

image is stored in

```
project/core/media/images/image_name.jpg
```

And the url i am getting after opening image in new tab is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/Bill_JcVkQAX.jpg
```

DEBUG is true (if that helps somehow)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwc9N.png)

[in urls.py and image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JS03.png)

Edit: in models.py:

```
class Bill(models.Model):

username = models.CharField(max_length=250, default = 0)
Shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0)
Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
Shop_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0)
Telephone_no = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0)
Total_items = models.IntegerField(default=0)
Bill_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
Bill_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

Comment: What is the HTTP return code ?

Comment: "GET /media/images/Bill_JcVkQAX.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3007

Comment: what is your bill_picture looks like in your model ?

Comment: Bill_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

Comment: How do you display it in HTML and what does it show ?

Comment: i want to display it as an item of table in HTML. It shows broken image. When I replace the bill.Bill_picture.url with "/static/assets/images/user/Bill.jpg", the static image is correctly displayed.  For static (in settings.py) - STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'.